# Setting up SSL in Dropwizard

Tags: java, ssl, https, keystore, dropwizard

I am trying to set up SSL in my [Dropwizard](http://www.dropwizard.io/0.9.2/docs/) server. I have got my SSL from GoDaddy and have received a couple of files from them namely:

1. gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt
2. b78*********.crt (basically a file named like a random string)

I have added the *gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt* certificate with alias *root* in my keystore and have added the other one with my domain alias.

My .yml configuration file looks like this: (I have just pasted the relevant section of the .yml file)

```
server:
  applicationConnectors:
  - type: http
    port: 8080
  - type: https
    port: 8443
    keyStorePath: keystore/myKeyStore.jks
    keyStorePassword: "myPassword"
    validateCerts: true

  adminConnectors:
  - type: http
    port: 8081
```

The problem is that whenever I am trying to launch my server I am receiving the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to retrieve certificate chain
```

When I set the *validateCerts* as false in the .yml above then, for obvious reason, this error goes away but when I try to access the URL I get:
[Connection closed error when trying to access the URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ct1aP.png)

I seem to be stuck real bad. My server is working perfectly with http but https just doesn't work! :(
Given my end goal of making https work and my current scenario, I have the following questions:

1. Am I handling the certificate files incorrectly?
2. Is there something missing in my .yml file that needs to be added or is there something wrong there?
3. Or is it something that I am missing from this picture altogether?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: I've had issues before with the bundle certs in the past. If you open it up it should have two certificates. Try importing each one individually

Comment: @Austin: The bundle has 3 entries in it. I did as you said above and now it says: java.lang.Exception: No certificate found in the keystore. I looked up my keystore using the command: keytool -list -keystore myKeyStore.jks and it shows me the 4 entries (3 from bundle and 1 which was there separately)

Comment: Did you also import `b78*********.crt`?

Comment: @Austin Yes I did. Was I not supposed to?

Comment: That should have worked :/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is finally resolved! Here is how I got it to work (hope this helps anyone who is having a hard time figuring out how to make SSL work with Dropwizard)

1. Firstly I had to concatenate the contents of `b78*********.crt` and `gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt` (make sure that the contents of the `b78*********.crt` are before the other file). Let's refer to that file as all_combined.crt from now.
2. Then I had to run this command to generate a .p12 file:

> C:\xampp\apache\bin>openssl.exe pkcs12 -export -in all_combined.crt
>   -inkey myKey.key -out keystore.p12 -CAfile temp.crt

myKey.key is the file that you must have created while generating the CSR to request the SSL from the authority.

3. Then I had to run this command to include the above generate .p12 into my keystore:

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin\keystore>..\keytool.exe -importkeystore -srckeystore keystore.p12 -destkeystore myKeyStore.jks -srcstoretype pkcs12 -deststoretype jks

That's all what is required in the keystore.

4. Finally I made a slight change in the .yml file:

> ```
> server:
>   applicationConnectors:
>   - type: http
>     port: 8080
>   - type: https
>     port: 8443
>     keyStorePath: ./keystore/myKeyStore.jks
>     keyStorePassword: "myPassword"
>     validateCerts: false
>     validatePeers: false
> ```

Note that I have set the validateCerts and validatePeers to false.
Then I just restarted my Dropwizard server and everything started working as expected and my server was listening and responding to port 8443! :-)

PS: I am not 100% sure on what each step does or whether each of these are required. But after searching for hours and hours I've finally got something to work and would definitely read about the details of this later when I have some time. Till then hope this unblocks someone who's stuck on it.

Comment: how do you generate your key? In the second command I am getting the error: unable to load private key

Comment: Does this configuration works when you do validateCerts: true?

Answer (score 6):

For others that will come I solved this problem in Dropwizard/Linux in another way.

First generate your keys:

```
 keytool -genkey -alias <aliasname> -keyalg RSA -keystore keystore.jks -keysize 2048
```

Then generate your CSR:

```
 keytool -certreq -alias <aliasname> -file csr.txt -keystore keystore.jks
```

Open your csr.txt and copy all content. Go to GoDaddy paste it and download the two .crt files as Others.

Then concatenate the contents of b78*********.crt and gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt (make sure that the contents of the b78*********.crt are before the other file). Let's refer to that file as all_combined.crt from now.

Finally combine your trust certs with your .jks:

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore keystore.jks -storepass <keystorepassword> -alias <aliasname> -file all_combined.crt
```

Then on your .yml file let this:

```
  applicationConnectors:
- type: http
  port: 8080
- type: https
  port: 8443
  keyStorePath: keystore.jks
  keyStorePassword: <keystorepassword>
  keyStoreType: JKS
  supportedProtocols: [TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2]
```

That is it, have fun!

Comment: What is the csr.txt file you mention?

Comment: @zafrani you generate when you execute this: keytool -certreq -alias <aliasname> -file csr.txt -keystore keystore.jks

Comment: If you receive any kind of errors when trying to combine your trust certs, please run this command keytool -exportcert -alias <aliasname> -keystore keystore.jks -keyalg RSA -file all_combined.crt

Comment: Why do I need the file all_combined.crt when in the docker yml file I am writing only the keystore.jks file?

Comment: Because you need to import the all_combined.crt that you merged by hand into your linux.